# Phone sign up and sign in custom policy in Azure ADB2C does not work

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I attempted to implement the custom policy to allow phone authentication while setting up Azure ADb2c for my application and tried to follow the instructions present here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication

I completed the prerequisites and believe I have everything setup correctly, but when i try to run the custom policy B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithPhone, I receive a message to my phone number (based out of india) with the verification code, but when I enter the verification code into the browser, i receive an HTTP 400 with too many requests and I'm not sure why. How do I ensure that this feature will be functional if I implement it into my application. Has anyone else faced this issue ? (tried incognito as well)

[image]

Comment: this might happen because you tried with same mobile number multiple times. Did you see other mobile numbers also hitting same issue?

Comment: @Ramakrishna - Yes, same issue on multiple mobile numbers

Comment: Yes, you can try with another number, please refer the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-error-messages

Error is **ServiceThrottled**

Comment: @Alex - I did try with another number and its the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: 
Looks like the file "Phone_Email_Base.xml" needed to be edited to include the tenant name in the two  and  tags. This was not mentioned in the tutorial and therefore took a bit of time to figure out why. I will be forwarding this to microsoft so that they can fix in their documentation.

Comment: Hi @vishnutej9492 Note that this is documented in [the **Get the phone sign-up & sign-in starter pack** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication#get-the-phone-sign-up--sign-in-starter-pack) at step 2.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett - right but that step doesnt take care of these two tags being replaced which causes the issue

https://imgur.com/55upTKm

Comment: Hi @vishnutej9492. Interesting. You shouldn't have to replace `{tenant}` in the **login-nonInteractive** technical profile. This is a reserved word.